# PulseAudio: Sound works after first pacat call

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I've got a strange problem with PulseAudio and a gstreamer python script (pygst). The script below works only if I execute a

```
cat /dev/urandom | pacat
```

before.

I've absolutely no idea what can cause this. Anyone else?

Script snippet:

```
self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("RadioPipe")
self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")
self.pipeline.add(self.player)
pulse = gst.element_factory_make("pulsesink", "cardname0")
self.player.set_property("audio-sink", pulse)
self.player.set_property('uri', self.mp3stream)
self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

System:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dpkg -l | egrep "pulse|alsa" | awk '{ print $2 " - " $3}'
alsa-base - 1.0.25+3~deb7u1
alsa-utils - 1.0.25-4
gstreamer0.10-alsa:armhf - 0.10.36-1.1
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:armhf - 0.10.31-3+nmu1
libpulse0:armhf - 2.0-6.1
pulseaudio - 2.0-6.1
pulseaudio-module-x11 - 2.0-6.1
pulseaudio-utils - 2.0-6.1
```